# PDF file not open in full screen in flutter

Tags: pdf, flutter

I used this library:
 **path_provider 1.5.1**

It's working fine 
but the pdf file not opened in full screen

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [flutter_full_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer#-readme-tab-) library?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/flutter_full_pdf_viewer.dart';

class ShowPdfPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String pdfPath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pdfPath = //your awesome path retrieved with path_provider;
    return PDFViewerScaffold(path: pdfPath);
  }
}
```